# Does python have an assignment operator for logical or?

Tags: python

Is there any way to to logical-or-assignment in python? Much like `a += 5`

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
a = True
a or= time_consuming_func_returning_bool()
```

to avoid calling the time-consuming function. That would be neat.

Comment: AFAIK, no language has this strange operator.

Comment: @liliscent C has the ternary conditional operator like `c ? a : b` where c gets assigned a if c is true and b if c is false.

Comment: @nj2237 This is totally irrelevant. C equivalent should be `||=`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @liliscent Ruby certainly has an `||=` operator.

Comment: @liliscent oh you are right, I have misunderstood the question! my bad

Comment: Javascript also has `||=` now

Answer (score 4):

Not really. Closest two options I have in mind:

```
a = a if a else b
a = a or b
```

Unless I am misunderstanding and you mean bitwise:

```
a=5  #101
a|=3 #010
```

result is `a==7` (`111`). Of course `|=` will work with `True` and `False`, but I'm not sure it's considered proper in the language:

```
a=True
a|=False
```

works, `a` will be `True`. The only concern here is semantic. If the usage is buried in deep code, someone skimming will assume you're using binary operations here - the above methods are more readable when considering  logic.

An even bigger caveat, mentioned by **@Moberg**, is that Boolean operators aren't lazy. Define

```
def b():
    print("Don't print this!")
    return False
```

Then

```
a|=b()
```

will print the string even though `a` is True and it doesn't matter what `b` is. This is because as far as the Boolean operation is concerned, `True` is just `1`, and `b` can be any number, so it must be evaluated. Using `a or b()` or `a if a else b()` will work as expected.

Comment: All this holds when using `&` and `and`.

Comment: `|=` does not short circuit. when doing `a |= b` b is evaluated

Comment: `|` is not equivalent to `or` and that's why `|=` evaluates the right operand each time.